# Data densification in ORACLE, using just views

Tags: oracle

I'm working with views. In one I have Purchase Orders with payment terms (30 days, 2 installments of 30 days (30/60), etc.) and other stuff:

```
PO    SUPPLIER    DELIVERY_DATE PAYMENT_TERMS
1     A           2016-11-10    30 DAYS
2     B           2016-11-10    30/60 DAYS
```

I'd like to produce a view with the payment schedule.
Due to licencing, i cannot work with tables, only views and I'm having a lot of trouble because of that (tried *materialized views for update*, no luck, as ORACLE throws the query is to complex for this).

This is what i'd like to get:

```
PO    SUPPLIER    DELIVERY_DATE PAYMENT_TERMS PAYMENT_DATE AMOUNT
1     A           2016-11-10    30 DAYS       2016-12-10   100%
2     B           2016-11-10    30/60 DAYS    2016-12-10   50%
2     B           2016-11-10    30/60 DAYS    2017-01-10   50%
```

Any tip?

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about licencing (using free version of Oracle for personal learning), but I would be surprised if you can't work with tables but are able to create materialized views - of ANY kind. Then - QUESTION: it seems 30/60 doesn't mean after 30 and 60 days, but rather after 1 month and 2 months? Dec.10 to Jan. 10 is a month, but 31 days. Or did you really mean 30 days and the output is wrong?

Comment: I just did some quick math, take the payment days with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that you'll need to decide what each different value of `Payment_Terms` really means, as there is no built-in rule to interpret "30/60 DAYS" as "One payment of 50% after 30 days, then a second payment of 50% after 60 days". So, I understand why the query would be too complex for a materialized view with automatic updating. Specifically, needing to create multiple rows in your output for a single row of input usually requires relatively complex logic (using `UNION`, fancy `JOIN` statements, etc.).

You can still use a materialized view, but you'll need to force the refresh of it on your own (periodically, or with a trigger if you have to).

Either way, a query (one of many) that will get what you want might look like this:

```
-- build the records for 30 DAYS
select po, supplier, delivery_date, payment_terms, (delivery_date + 30) as payment_date, 100 as amount
from The_Table
where payment_terms = '30 DAYS'
union all
-- build the records for the FIRST payment for 30/60
select po, supplier, delivery_date, payment_terms, (delivery_date + 30) as payment_date, 50 as amount
from The_Table
where payment_terms = '30/60 DAYS'
union all
-- build the records for the SECOND payment for 30/60
select po, supplier, delivery_date, payment_terms, (delivery_date + 60) as payment_date, 50 as amount
from The_Table
where payment_terms = '30/60 DAYS'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you bet baby, you bet.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below assumes "30" is a conventional way to mean "month" - all computations are based on months rather than days. If instead "days" is meant literally, the solution can be easily adapted. I assumed the "payment_terms" sting is always EXACTLY in the format you presented (one of the two possibilities), and that the second number, if it exists, is an exact multiple of the first. I added two more test rows. I can't think of any reason why this can't be made into a fast refreshable materialized view. (Not sure about FOR UPDATE - what would you want to update through this view?)

Note - if the percentages in the last column are meant to be used in further calculations, they should NOT be made into strings (ending with the % symbol); rather, they should be numbers, like 1.0000 or 0.3333 or 0.5000.

```
with
     inputs ( po, supplier, delivery_date, payment_terms ) as (
       select 1, 'A', date '2016-11-10', '30 DAYS'     from dual union all
       select 2, 'B', date '2016-11-10', '30/60 DAYS'  from dual union all
       select 3, 'C', date '2015-03-13', '90 DAYS'     from dual union all
       select 4, 'D', date '2015-10-01', '90/270 DAYS' from dual
     ),
     prep ( po, supplier, delivery_date, payment_terms, freq, num ) as (
       select po, supplier, delivery_date, payment_terms,
              to_number(regexp_substr(payment_terms, '\d+', 1, 1)) / 30,
              nvl(to_number(regexp_substr(payment_terms, '\d+', 1, 2)) /
                    to_number(regexp_substr(payment_terms, '\d+', 1, 1)),  1)
       from inputs
     )
select po, supplier, delivery_date, payment_terms,
       add_months ( delivery_date, freq * level ) as payment_date,
       to_char(100/num, '999.99') || '%' as payment_amount
from prep
connect by level <= num
       and prior po = po
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by po, payment_date
;


        PO S DELIVERY_DATE PAYMENT_TERMS PAYMENT_DATE PAYMENT_AMOUNT
---------- - ------------- ------------- ------------ --------------
         1 A 10-NOV-2016   30 DAYS       10-DEC-2016   100.00%
         2 B 10-NOV-2016   30/60 DAYS    10-DEC-2016    50.00%
         2 B 10-NOV-2016   30/60 DAYS    10-JAN-2017    50.00%
         3 C 13-MAR-2015   90 DAYS       13-JUN-2015   100.00%
         4 D 01-OCT-2015   90/270 DAYS   01-JAN-2016    33.33%
         4 D 01-OCT-2015   90/270 DAYS   01-APR-2016    33.33%
         4 D 01-OCT-2015   90/270 DAYS   01-JUL-2016    33.33%
```